# Application context errors when locally testing a (Python) Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-contacts-api

I am trying to locally test a Python function that I hope to deploy as a Google Cloud Function. These functions seem to be essentially Flask based, and I have found that the best way to return JSON is to use Flask's jsonify function. This seems to work fine when deployed, but I want to set up some local unit tests, and here is where I got stuck. Simply adding the line to import jsonify, results in the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

There are several posts here on Stackoverflow that seem relevant to this issue, and yet Google Cloud Functions do not really follow the Flask pattern. There is no app context, as far as I can tell, and there are no decorators. All of the examples I've found have not been useful to this particular use case. Can anyone suggest a method for constructing a unit test that will respect the application context and still jibe with the GCF pattern here.

I have a unittest, which I can share, but you will see the same error when you run the following, with the method invocation inside of **main**.

```
import os
import json
from flask import jsonify
from unittest.mock import Mock

def dummy_request(request):

    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json and 'document' in request_json:
        document = request_json['document']
    else:
        raise ValueError("JSON is invalid, or missing a 'docuemnt' property")

    data = document
    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {"document":"This is a test document"}
    request = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data)
    result = dummy_request(request)
    print(result)
```

Comment: I started down this path, because I thought I required either Flask jsonify or Response methods to produce the correct output for a Google Cloud Function. I am more used to AWS Lambda, where there is a documented proxy format in JSON which each function must produce.

I have since realized that I can simply return a JSON string. And as for headers and status codes, those can be returned as part of a tuple, as in the documentation:

return ('Hello World!', 200, headers)

So, the easiest option for me is to remove all of the Flask response stuff from my function and test normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'd recommend you to take a look at Flask's documentation on how to test Flask apps](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/), it's described pretty well how to setup a test and get an application context.

P.S. `jsonify` requires application context, but `json.dumps` is not. Maybe you can use the latter?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the documentation and was able to put together a simple working example for testing a Flask application. However, the Google Cloud Function is not _really_ a Flask app. It has no decorators and its method must receive the request object. So, this route did not really work.

For now, it seems the best option is to simply return the json using json.dumps, as you suggested. 

I'm no longer certain where I picked up the jsonify idea -- somewhere else on Stackoverflow probably.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to test whether `flask.jsonify` works as expected, right? It's a third-party function.

What you're actually trying to test is that `flask.jsonify` was called with the right data, so instead you can just patch `flask.jsonify`, and make assertions on whether the mock was called:

```
import flask
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

def dummy_request(request):

    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json and 'document' in request_json:
        document = request_json['document']
    else:
        raise ValueError("JSON is invalid, or missing a 'docuemnt' property")

    data = document
    return flask.jsonify(data)


@patch('flask.jsonify')
def test(mock_jsonify):
    data = {"document": "This is a test document"}
    request = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data)
    dummy_request(request)
    mock_jsonify.assert_called_once_with("This is a test document")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked with pytest and the example above. I still had some context errors when I moved the test function outside of the Flask function into tests.py. I'm still working on it, though.

Comment: Not sure I follow, but feel free to ask a new question and I'd be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. As you've said the flask testing doesn't seem to fit well with Cloud Functions and I was happy with how the code worked so didn't want to change that. Adding an application context in setUp() of testing then using it for the required calls worked for me. Something like this...

```
import unittest
import main
from flask import Flask

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)

    def test_something(self):      

        with self.app.app_context():
            (body, code) = main.request_something()

        self.assertEqual(200, code, "The request did not return a successful response")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```